# SOAP webservice connection through SSL

Tags: java, ssl, soap, webservice-client, saaj

i'm trying to write a java based webservice client to consume a secure webservice over netting IP. This is my first time so i need some serious help here please. All i get from my vendor is three different .cer files and a wsdl link. After some research what i did that created a new keystore with `keytool -import -file myCert.cer -alias testkey -keystore test.ks` and added these three .cer files into it, nothing else. Then i wrote below code for testing. Tell me if anything else i need to do to make a successful connection.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class SOAPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        String request = "my xml based SOAP string";

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/web/cert/test.ks"); 
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();

        String url = "https://example.com:31746/Service/service.serviceagent";
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);

        // Process the SOAP Response
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult( outWriter );
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);  
        StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer(); 
        response = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(response);

        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return response;
}

}
```

But when i run this java code as a standalone through command line (as i have no other way of testing it) i get below exceptions on screen.

```
 %% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 352
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 32
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 960
 main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 208
 main, called close()
 main, called closeInternal(true)
 main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
 main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
 Dec 16, 2016 11:51:54 AM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
 SEVERE: SAAJ0010: Unable to read response
 java.lang.NullPointerException
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.readFully(HttpSOAPConnection.java:544)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:313)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)

 Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to
 read response: null
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)
 Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: null
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:337)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         ... 1 more

 CAUSE:

 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: null
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:337)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)

 CAUSE:

 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to read response: null
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:337)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)
```

**UPDATE**

If i put `?wsdl` in the end of URL. I get below exception

```
 Dec 16, 2016 1:01:16 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl identifyContentType
 SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
 Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Co
 ntent-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)
 Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error messa
 ge instead of a SOAP response?
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         ... 1 more

 CAUSE:

 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead
 of a SOAP response?
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)

 CAUSE:

 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead
 of a SOAP response?
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:85)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:327)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:32)
```

**UPDATE 2**

After changing property from `keystore` to `truststore`

```
 %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
 main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
 main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
 main, called closeSocket()
 main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path buil
 ding failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requ
 ested target
 main, called close()
 main, called closeInternal(true)
 Dec 16, 2016 4:50:49 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
 SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
 Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
 com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message se
 nd failed
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
         at AKUSOAPClient.main(AKUSOAPClient.java:34)
 Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:278)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
         ... 1 more
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: su
 n.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
         at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
         at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
         at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java
 :185)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
         ... 2 more
 Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertP
 athBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
         at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
         at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
         at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
         at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
         at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
         at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
         at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
         ... 14 more
 Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to reques
 ted target
         at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
         at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
         at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
         ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not the underlying issue, but you need you change `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` by  `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.

- The **trustStore** determines whether the remote
  authenticationcredentials (and thus the connection) should be
  trusted.
- The **keyStore** determines which authentication credentials to send to
  the remote host.

Probably the error is due to your request is not a valid SOAP message, and it is causing a null response from server.

```
String request = "my xml based SOAP string";
```

I suggest you debug the soap messages interchanged and use a JAX-WS client generated from WSDL instead of building the SOAP messages from scratch

Comment: Thanks for the response. One more thing i would like to add here. I had a thought that it might be some problem with the URL so i added `?wsdl` in the end and now i get this exception

Comment: Also the problem is that as i said it's over netted IP and system where i can only access it is sun solaris without UI. So i cannot even view the wsdl from there but can only save it through wget command

Comment: This is not the problem. The `?wsdl` is usually used in endpoints to provide the WSDL file. You can see at the log trace that the server is responding with a text file: 'Invalid Content-Type:text/html`. You do not need an UI to get the WSDL. Use the address provided by server to download the wsdl and generate the code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually i am not making the message from scratch. I will get the full SOAP message as a string in input arguments from another system and then i have to return back the response received. My java code is kind of integrator between these two systems so i cannot create message string by myself. Can you please suggest something to help me out

Comment: ok, then you do not need the WSDL. With "full SOAP message" do you mean body + header?. In this case you only need a `URLConnection` and configure the truststore.

Comment: Here is the exact input string that i get. `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nis="http://www.exapmle.com/SrvRequest.xsd"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><nis:request_payment><nis:header><nis:version></nis:version><nis:msg_id></nis:msg_id></nis:header><nis:body><nis:card_no></nis:card_no></nis:body></nis:request_payment></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>` Also please can you guide me how to create an configure truestore with the three .cer files that i recieved. Many Thanks

Comment: This is a full SOAP message, so just open a URL connection and post the text to server using `application/xml` `content-type`. The server will return a SOAP response

Comment: The `keytool` command you have posted in your question to import a certificate into a JKS keystore is correct. Use it with `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/web/cert/test.ks");`

Comment: I did make the change and tried it with `trustStore` but now i'm getting other exceptions. Please see update to my question

Comment: `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` means your client is not trusting server identity.  The main cause is that the system has not found the JKS path or you have not correctly imported the root CA certificate. List the contents of the JKS and check the path

Comment: Can you please guide me where to set the JKS path. I also have a jks file but don't know where to use it. Sorry for the silly questions but i'm totally new to this thing

Comment: I have answered  above `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/web/cert/test.ks");` The second param is the absolute path to your JKS. Remember also to configure the password `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also please help me out understanding these certificate thing. I'm a little bit confused here. As i said my vendor gave me 3 .cer files i don't know what they are and what's their purpose. They have the server hosting webservice and i'm writing the client side. Do i also need to get my own certificates or private keys from some CA or something like that ?

Comment: It is the public part of the server certificate, including the certificatation chain of the issuing certification authority (it is a hierarchy). In the JKS it is only necessary to include the root certificate. You do not need extra certificates

Comment: It is two way SSL connection. Just trustStore is not working for me. I believe i also need client side certificates. can you please help me out with that ? How to create or get them. I will appreciate if you can give me a detailed idea about that

Comment: Then configure also  a Keystore using javax.net.ssl.keyStore. impor the private key and the certificate for the authentication. The server provider MUST provide you the key+certificate to use or the constraints to generate the self-signed certificate and provide back the public key so you can be identifier. Look in STackOverflow how to generate a certificate. There are many posts. You can use Keystore Explorer application too

Comment: Thank you so much for the `trustStore` vs `keyStore`, that helped me a lot in my understanding of ssl / soap messages.